# Rails Mailer does not work when deploying to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, railstutorial.org, mailer

Following Michael Hartl's tutorial for account activationm (Ch 11),when deploying to Heroku and creating new user, I get the **"We're sorry, but something went wrong."** message. The user gets created in the database but the email does not get sent so the account cannot be activated.

I don't know why but when getting the "We're sorry..." error, the browser shows me the " **herokuapp.com/users**" adress, when the controller says to redirect to root.

Here the users controller:

```
     class UsersController < ApplicationController
            before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
            before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
            before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

            def index
              @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
            end

            def show
              @user = User.find(params[:id])
              redirect_to root_url and return unless  @user.activated?
            end

            def new
              @user = User.new
            end

            def create
              @user = User.new(user_params)
              if @user.save
                @user.send_activation_email
                flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
                redirect_to root_url
              else
                render 'new'
              end
            end

            def edit
              @user = User.find(params[:id])
            end

            def update
              @user = User.find(params[:id])
              if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
                flash[:success] = "Profile updated!"
                redirect_to @user
              else
                render 'edit'
              end
            end

            def destroy
              User.find(params[:id]).destroy
              flash[:success] = "User deleted!"
              redirect_to users_url
            end

            private

              def user_params
                params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                             :password_confirmation)
              end

              # Before filters

              # Confirms a logged-in user.
              def logged_in_user
                unless logged_in?
                  store_location
                  flash[:danger] = "Please log in"
                  redirect_to login_url
                end
              end

              # Confirms the correct user.
              def correct_user
                @user = User.find(params[:id])
                redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
              end

              # Confirms an admin user.
              def admin_user
                redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
              end

          end
```

and model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base                
                attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token
                before_save   :downcase_email
                before_create :create_activation_digest

                # Validates presence and lenght for the user name
                validates :name,  presence: true, 
                                  length: { maximum: 50 }

                # Validates presence, length, format and uniqueness for user email
                VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
                validates :email, presence: true, 
                                  length: { maximum: 255 }, 
                                  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

                # User has a secure password (password_digest), length and presence
                has_secure_password
                validates :password, presence: true, 
                                     length: { minimum: 6 },
                                     allow_nil: true


               # VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20})"
               # validates :password, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }

                 # Returns the hash digest of the given string. (only for tests)
                def User.digest(string)
                  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                                BCrypt::Engine.cost
                  BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
                end


              # FOR REMEMBER ME

                # Returns a random token for safe "remember me".
                def User.new_token
                  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
                end

                # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
                def remember
                  self.remember_token = User.new_token
                  update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
                end


                # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
                def authenticated?(attribute, token)
                  digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
                  return false if digest.nil?
                  BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
                end

                # Forgets a user.
                def forget
                  update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
                end

                # Activates an account.
                def activate
                  update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)
                end


                # Sends activation email.
                def send_activation_email
                  UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
                end



                private

                # Converts email to all lower-case.
                def downcase_email
                  self.email = email.downcase
                end


                # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
                def create_activation_digest
                  self.activation_token  = User.new_token
                  self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
                end
              end
```

application and user mailers:

```
    class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default from: "noreply@example.com"
      layout 'mailer'
    end
```

-

```
    class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

      def account_activation(user)
        @user = user
        mail to: @user.email, subject: "Account activation"
      end
    end
```

Production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
                  config.cache_classes = true

                  config.eager_load = true

                  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
                  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

                  config.public_file_server.enabled = true

                  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
                  config.assets.compile = false

                  config.assets.digest = true

                   config.force_ssl = true

                  config.log_level = :debug

                  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
                  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
                  host = 'whispering-spire-86793.herokuapp.com'
                  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
                  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
                    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
                    :port           => '587',
                    :authentication => :plain,
                    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
                    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
                    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
                    :enable_starttls_auto => true
                  }

                  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

                  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

                  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

                  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
                end
```

And heroku logs

```
    2016-07-14T12:22:19.113508+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in         cluster mode...
    2016-07-14T12:22:19.113539+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.4-p230), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
    2016-07-14T12:22:20.539342+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9375
    2016-07-14T12:22:21.039497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2016-07-14T12:22:22.459846+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=whispering-spire-86793.herokuapp.com request_id=7bff9a3c- 3151-48a4-87bc-ba207b1fa10e fwd="88.12.236.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=390ms status=500 bytes=1714
     2016-07-14T12:22:22.684571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=whispering-spire-86793.herokuapp.com request_id=afd1130c-9864-4650-a5c7-fccd8446039b fwd="88.12.236.151" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=188
     2016-07-14T12:22:23.912741+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=whispering-spire-86793.herokuapp.com request_id=62a47e7f-33c3-42b6-b700-2219cfa8ada1 fwd="88.12.236.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=188
```

Comment: WHAT ERROR IT IS SHOWING IN THE LOG ?

Comment: read the erros with the command: `heroku logs`

Comment: That is the thing, I posted the log from the heroku website, at the end of the post, I get the same running heroku logs:

Comment: You need to run 'heroku logs --tail', then try adding a user again, and you will see the error in the logs live. Post those logs up if you're still having trouble.

Comment: :S
I still get the same... 

2016-07-14T13:02:11.820878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=whispering-spire-86793.herokuapp.com request_id=3d43407b-53db-4ba5-8084-94514e567d85 fwd="88.12.236.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=394ms status=500 bytes=171

and I am still concerned why it tries to get the /users page when the controller says to go to root!

Comment: Can you please give me a link to your github project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem. Since everything was working in development, I figured that it must be a problem with the development environment.

So I copied and pasted from Hartl's tutorial for the file config/environments/production.rb from chapter 11, listing 11.41. I must have had a typo in that file on my first try, because my live app is working now.

Also, notice that the line

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

is already included in the file by default. But Hartl's code includes

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

So you need to delete the "false" line.

For convenience, the full code is:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = '<your heroku app>.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Good luck!